# How to use `root_url` in the ActiveModel::Serializer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

I wanna edit entities URLs from DB by adding for them. How I can use `root_url` or `root_path` in a serializer?

Something like this:

```
class TrackSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title, :mp3, :ogg
  has_one :promo_album

  def mp3
    root_url + object.mp3
  end

  def ogg
    root_url + object.ogg
  end
end
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just forgot to define `root` param in the `routes.rb`. `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` helps me to get `root_path` in the serializer.

Comment: Please mark a response to help others find the answer when searching and finding your question.

Answer (score 7):

The issue is that Rails.application.routes.url_helpers isn't included by default here. If you replace

```
root_url
```

with

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.root_url
```

you should get the results you're looking for.

Comment: There is no results. Only errors :(

NoMethodError - undefined method `root_url' for #<Module:0x007f851581ba18>: app/serializers/track_serializer.rb:6:in `mp3'
 active_model_serializers (0.10.0.rc3) lib/active_model/serializer.rb:139:in `block in attributes'
 active_model_serializers (0.10.0.rc3) lib/active_model/serializer.rb:137:in `attributes'

Comment: Glad to hear that worked, would you be able to accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

**Rails 4:** I've set a config variable in the application controller.

```
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_root

  protected
  def set_root
    Rails.application.config.root_url = root_url
  end
```

Which I access in my model like this:

```
Rails.application.config.root_url
```

Note: It requires that you have a `root` configured in routes.rb.